# Insert data to a multipicklist using PHP API Call

Tags: rest-api, php

I am new to SalesForce. I am trying to create a new "Account" object in SalesForce using PHP API call.

This works perfectly when I am not passing values to the multipicklist. When I pass data to the multipicklist field it throws me an error.

This is the error message I am getting.

> SFDC ERROR : bad value for restricted picklist field: Oracle
> bad value for restricted picklist field: Microsoft
> bad value for restricted picklist field: Mambu
> bad value for restricted picklist field: Comply Advantage

> ERROR Code :- INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST

The values saved in my database are semicolon separated.  **Oracle;Microsoft;Mambu;Comply Advantage**

This is my array that I am passing over to SFDC.

```
$content = [
        'Name' => 'My Account Name', // this the account name
        'Current_Partnerships__c' => 'Oracle;Microsoft;Mambu;Comply Advantage'
    ];
```

This is the field value list.

[image]

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong and how to fix this error.
Thank You.

Comment: Have you double checked the picklist configuration?

Comment: hmm..can you please point me what to check? This is literally my first experience with SFDC integration to be honest.

Comment: You have included it, but some of it is cropped (and Comply Advantage is not expanded to verify it is active).

Comment: i have updated the image to display all the config.